# Wild Bootstrap F-test

Tags: bootstrap, f-test

Is anyone aware of code for a wild bootstrap F-test? Namely, testing joint significance of several coefficients where the standard errors of each coefficient are computed using a wild bootstrap.

The following paper exposits the theory, but I wanted to see if anyone has implemented this in practice?

Baltagi, B., Kao, C., Na, S. (2013) [Testing for cross-sectional dependence in a panel factor model using the wild bootstrap F test](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00362-013-0499-9) *Statistical Papers*,  *54*:1067–1094.

Comment: The stata package `boottest`  implements wild-bootstrap based F-tests. It's optimized to run fast wild *cluster* bootstraps, and if you do not cluster, the command might become memory-intensive.

Comment: Further, the `wildmeta` package implements wild cluster bootstrap F-tests in R. `WildBootTests.jl` implements wild cluster bootstrap F-test in Julia, and `fwildclusterboot` allows to call `WildBootTests.jl` from within R.